# url rewriting for a website

Tags: regex, .htaccess, iis, iis-8

I have very small website where the links are few pages, I want to write few regex so it can match and if match they should redirect to that page, I had already installed `urlrewrite` in `IIS 8`

the url i have is:

```
website.com/page1.cfm 
 or http://www.website.com/page1.cfm or http://website.com/page1.cfm
```

to this:

```
http://website.com/page1
```

removing the extension

Comment: When someone is accessing in browser `http://website.com/page1 ` you want to show content of this page `website.com/page1.cfm `. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match all 3 of your uri formats:

```
^((http:\/\/|)(www\.|)website\.com\/.+\.cfm)$
```

To see it in action, and see explanations, go here: https://regexr.com/3ja85

Note: Replace 'website' with your domain.

This regex will match any sub page of your domain (website.com/[anything].cfm)

**EDIT:**
This regex will return the uri of the 3 formats without the extension while enforcing its presence at the end of a uri:

```
^((http:\/\/|)(www\.|)website\.com\/.+)(?=\.cfm)
```